# How to determine the data triggered in useeffect react js

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a useffect with two variables being passed, `noteId and refresh`.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (Is noteId triggered){
      // code here
   }
   if (Is refresh triggered){
      // code here
   }
}, [noteId, refresh]); <----
```

Is there any way to determine which data (either noteId or refresh) has triggered the useEffect?

Answer (score 0):

use separate `useEffect` hooks for each `noteId` and `refresh`

Comment: `noteId` & `refresh` shares the same method when triggered, except that on refresh, there are added codes. If I will separate them, both methods will take effect at the same time, and the problem lies since there will be two API request in one refresh.

Comment: You could have three useEffects. one for refresh, one for noteId and one for both. It would be bad coding but it can be done. However, if you can paste in some code it would be helpful